# wheel odometry and laser_scan_matcher

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello . I am using ros_arduino_bridge.
https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge

Can I  connect directly the ouput of ros_arduino_bridge (odom message) to laser_scan_matcher ( http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher ) ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225005/wheel-odometry-and-laser_scan_matcher/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you have a supported motor controller and encoder interface, the ros_arduino_bridge package publishes wheel odometry data on the /odom topic.  Since the laser_scan_matcher has the option of subscribing to the /odom topic to augment the laser scan matching, then the answer is "yes".

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2016-01-26**:
then, no need doing about covariance calculating for output of  ros_arduino_bridge , isnt it ?

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-01-27**:
The ros_arduino_bridge package does not publish covariance values.  I don't know if laser_scan_matcher requires covariance when subscribing to /odom.

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2016-01-28**:
I am sorry but I do not know about covariance. you think does it (below link) requires covariance ?

https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/indigo/laser_scan_matcher/src/laser_scan_matcher.cpp

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-01-28**:
Looking at the code at https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/indigo/laser_scan_matcher/src/laser_scan_matcher.cpp, it does not look like wheel odometry covariance is used.  However, perhaps someone else on the forum knows for sure.

**Comment by [femitof](https://answers.ros.org/users/39985/femitof/) on 2020-04-05**:
Hi, howw did you connect the output of the ros_arduino_bridge to the laser scan matcher? Thanks @osmancns